# Como adicionar um botão nas colunas no datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando adicionar alguns botões no DataTable usando `columnDefs`, mas no entanto, não consigo, e quando removo umas colunas, ele não fica alinhado conforme a ordem

Meu código atual é esse:

```
var grid = $("#grid").dataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "/Scripts/libs/dataTable/ptBr.txt"
    },
    "ajax": "/grupo/data",
    "columnDefs": [
         {
             "data": "Id",
             "targets": 0
         },
        {
            "data": "Nome",
            "targets": 1
        },
        {
            "data": "Descricao",
            "targets": 2
        },
        {
          "render": function (data, type, row) {
              return "<a href='/editar/" + row.Id + "' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a>"
          },
          "targets": 3
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return "<a href='/editar/" + row.Id + "' class='btn btn-danger'>Deletar</a>"
            },
            "targets": 4
        }
    ]
});
```

e da o seguinte erro:

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

E não rendeniza nem os dados

Mas se eu removo as colunas dos links, ele aparece os dados

Comment: Rod, não conheço o `dataTable`, mas o fato da quarta coluna não ter o `targets` não causa problema?

Comment: da erro se eu remover os targets

Comment: Minha observação era pra incluir o `targets: 3` nessa quarta coluna.

Comment: já tentei Wakim, acho que esqueci de postar no exemplo, vou editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a abordagem deva ser um pouco diferente. O [exemplo que encontrei](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3193/adding-link-or-button-into-the-datatable-row) configura a coluna da seguinte forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "100%",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "aoColumns":[
                null,null,null,null,null,null,
               { "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<a href=/cgi/empdetails.php?showemp=' + oObj.aData[0] + '>' + 'More' + '</a>';
                  }
               }
            ],
            "sAjaxSource": "scripts/team_processing.php"
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Passando a ideia para o seu script:

```
var grid = $("#grid").dataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "/Scripts/libs/dataTable/ptBr.txt"
    },
    "ajax": "/grupo/data",
    "aoColumns": [
         {
             "data": "Id",
         },
        {
            "data": "Nome",
        },
        {
            "data": "Descricao",
        },
        {
          "fnRender": function (data, type, row) {
              return "<a href='/editar/" + row.Id + "' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a>"
          },
        },
        {
            "fnRender": function (data, type, row) {
                return "<a href='/editar/" + row.Id + "' class='btn btn-danger'>Deletar</a>"
            }
        }
    ]
});
```